# Slow transfer with memory stick (819 kb/s)

Tags: performance, speed, file-transfer, memorystick

What do I do to optimize the file transfer rate of a Memory Stick Duo?

The file transfer was not like this when it was still new.  Can reformatting give new life to a memory stick?

It takes about 20 minutes just to transfer 1Gb of file from computer to memory stick.
The computer is decent enough. 2.50Ghz processor, 2Gb ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to check if the device has suddenly become USB 1.1 instead of 2.

This is explained with screen captures in [Checking for USB 2](http://www.usbman.com/Guides/checking_for_usb_2.htm), but in a nutshell, open Device Manager and check if under "Universal Serial Bus controllers" you have "ENHANCED USB Host Controller".

Also check in the BIOS, if USB 2 is suddenly turned off.

Other thing to try is re-installing the PCI to USB host controller driver.

It's also possible (but unlikely) that the USB device has become highly fragmented, which can be fixed by a reformatting.

Comment: Even if USB2 is turned on, some of the motherboard USB ports may be fixed at 1.1, especially the front panel ports. Nrew, try your memory stick on some back panel ports that are wired directly to the motherboard.